# How to select the last td in every tr using .each() and .last()?

Tags: jquery

I want to select the last td in every tr using the .each() loop and .last() method.

This is what I'm doing:

```
$('tr:has(td)').children().each(function(){return $(this).parent().last()});
```

But that code returns every td and not just the last one from each row.

Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply write

```
$('tr > td:last-child')
```

Your code is wrong for a number of reasons:

- `.last()` selects the last element in the current set; you need `.children().last()`
- `.each()` doesn't do anything with the return value of its callback; you want `.map()`
- `children()` makes your callback run for every cell in each row.