# Last td of each line in html table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I know it's already been asked before, however I've tried previous solutions and they're not working for me.

I've got a HTML table as so which is being generated by AJAX:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="7" summary="Procedure Tabulate: Table 1" frame="box" rules="groups" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="c m Header">&nbsp;</th>
            <th scope="col" class="c Header">reel</th>
            <th scope="col" class="c Header">budgete</th>
            <th scope="col" class="c Header">ecart</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="l t RowHeader">Fours</th>
            <td class="r b Data">15 341,10</td>
            <td class="r b Data">15 540,90</td>
            <td nowrap="" class="r b Data">  -1.29% </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="l t RowHeader">Hifi</th>
            <td class="r b Data">10 578,60</td>
            <td class="r b Data"> 9 962,50</td>
            <td class="r b Data">   6.18% </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="l t RowHeader">Magneto</th>
            <td class="r b Data">10 090,10</td>
            <td class="r b Data">10 495,60</td>
            <td nowrap="" class="r b Data">  -3.86% </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="l t RowHeader">Total</th>
            <td class="r b Data">36 009,80</td>
            <td class="r b Data">35 999,00</td>
            <td class="r b Data">   1.04% </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't have much control over the classes in the table as they are being created by another group of people using SAS (Statistical Analysis Software).

I would like to get the last td of each row in tbody.

For the moment I've got the following jQuery to do the job:

```
$( '#ajax-area table tbody tr td:last' ).addClass( 'result' );
```

This isn't adding the class to the td.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: When do you execute the addClass? Did you make sure it is after the ajax call (on success)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select the last td in every tr using .each() and .last()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309839/how-to-select-the-last-td-in-every-tr-using-each-and-last)

Comment: Can you post the full code for the AJAX call in addition to the line to add the class? What you've posted looks like it should be fine (assuming that table *is* inside an element with `id` of `ajax-area`).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

```
$( 'table tbody tr td:last-child').addClass( 'result' );
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tZN3X/)

Answer (score 6):

This should work for you:

```
$('#ajax-area table tbody tr').find('td:last').addClass('result');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xK8EC/